# Provide definition of constructor template outside a class template

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, constructor

Consider the following class template with a constructor template:

```
template <class T>
class C{
    public:
    T val_;
    std::string str_;
    
    template <typename S>
    C(const S& str);
    // C(const S& str) : str_(str) {}; // Valid definition of constructor within class body
    
    void print(){std::cout << str_;}
};
```

I'm, however, trying to define the constructor outside of the class, but I can't seem to figure out a way to account for the type `S`.

```
template <typename T, typename S> // incorrect as too many parameters
C<T>::C(const S& str) : str_(str) {};
```

Alternatively, I tried

```
template <typename T>
C<T>::C(const std::string& str) : str_(str) {};
```

which also does not work (and probably defeats the purpose of `S`)

1. How can I correctly define this constructor outside the class.
2. Does such a pattern (where class template parameters differ from constructor template parameters) serve any practical purpose? An example would be very helpful.

Comment: Did you try: `template <class T> template <typename S> C<T>::C(const S&) { /* ... */}` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The correct syntax is:**

```
template <class T>
template <class S>
C<T>::C(const S& str)
{
    // ...
}
```

**Regarding your second question:**

One example of using this pattern (of templating a ctor) is the way to achieve **type-erasure** in C++ using templates.
This article has some examples: [What is type erasure - Arthur O'Dwyer](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/03/18/what-is-type-erasure/) (search for *"templated constructor"*).
Or this 10 minutes clip that demonstrates it: [Type Erasure (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZPk8HuyrKXU).

Comment: Yes, that solves it. Learnt about this type of syntactical arrangement today.